# jquery class-selector vs qualified class-selector

Tags: jquery, performance, class, jquery-selectors, selector

I am currently  writing my bachelorthesis about webperformance and just came across some results I didn't expect.

As Paul Irish or jquery itself recommend it's always best to descend from an id.

http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

So I would have expected that $('.class') should be slower than $('#id class') or $('#id').find('.class').

I tested it on jsperf and came to a pretty intersting result:

http://jsperf.com/selektor/2

[image: Results]

It seems like that it really depends on the browser, but I really didn't expect $('.class') to perform so well, expecially on Chrome it's way faster than those who descend from an id.

Which makes sense to me is the following explanation, but why is the difference so big upon those browsers. Are the engines so different?

> The difference is when using a single class or id lookup, getElementsByClassName and getElementById can be used which are way faster than querySelector. You'll see it's 10 times faster in modern browsers.

Source: http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-tag-qualfied-class-selector/38

So what's your opinion on that?

Comment: That (strongly) indicates that modern browsers also cache class entries (as well as their usual fast ID lookup table). Any extra code overhead (adding an id search) will slow it down. Nice to know.

Comment: Added an answer to the only real question below, as you have exposed a really useful piece of information. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the only real question in your question: "Which makes sense to me is the following explanation, but why is the difference so big upon those browsers. **Are the engines so different?**"

The answer is of course **"Yes"**. Those 3 browsers all stem from different code-bases and different coding methods will result in dramatically different speed difference. e.g. "ask 3 coders for a solution and you will get 3 different solutions" :)

The most important thing to note is that *class only* searches are actually very fast on modern browsers, despite suggestions to the contrary. Adding additional checks (even an ID selector) will only slow down class searches. That implies that most, if not all, modern browsers keep a cache of classes vs. elements. That was probably intended for faster CSS processing, but a side-effect is also fast class-based searches.